# sum a small range between two special marks

Tags: vba

Sample data:

```
Column A       Column B

63843       
60208        
57606   
130717           1    
190407   
186980           1    
167839   
180043   
174384           1   
170289           1  
107142   
87628      
41637  
48807            1    
57602   
51537
```

Column A is concentration and column B are something like marks.

I want to sum the concentration after one mark to the next mark into a new column (column C), the concentration besides "1" is the last element of one sum.
For example: sum(63843:130717),sum(190407:186980),sum(167839:174384),etc.

If marks are stick to each other, like between 174384 with 170289, the sum is 170289.

I hope I express it clearly. I know I should write some code in this part, but I totally have no idea. I think I should use something like:

Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Formula = "=IF(B1=1,TEXT(SUM(...........),""...................""),"""")"

Thank you so much.

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C1").Formula = "=IF(B1=1,A1,"""")"
    .Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).Formula = "=IF(B2=1,SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($C$1:C1),"""")"
End With
```

[image]

Comment: Wooooooo  amazing!!! I am a beginner of VBA, it cost me long time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

VBA solution:

EDIT: Realized I was missing a 1 in my example so it doesn't match yours, but you get the gist I suppose.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SumBetweenMarks()
Dim sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, myvalue As Long, i as long

Set sht = ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

myvalue = 0
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> 1 Then
        myvalue = myvalue + Range("A" & i).Value
    Else
        myvalue = myvalue + Range("A" & i).Value
        Range("C" & i).Value = myvalue
        myvalue = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I have a question, why I run "myvalue = myvalue + Range("A" & i).Value" it was an error 13: Type mismatch?

Comment: @PhoenixNing That means that whatever's in that cell in column A is not really a number, is it like `124124A` or something?